# program receive signal SIGSEGV segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct

i have make  MCVE exemple, the program crash and return 255 after i've add to unpack_code function the following(before that it was working):

```
int ch_bit; 
unsigned int *ch_word; 
ch_bit = *p_ch_bit;
```

to the bellow code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct melp_param *par;

void unpack_code( unsigned int **p_ch_beg, int *p_ch_bit, 
        int *p_code, int numbits, int wsize,unsigned int erasemaks)
{
      int ret_code;
      int ch_bit;
      unsigned int *ch_word;
      ch_bit = *(p_ch_bit);
      *p_code = 0;

}

void melp_chn_read(struct melp_param *par, 
                   struct melp_param *prev_par)
{



}

int main(void)
{
      int bit_buffer[42];

    unpack_code(NULL, NULL, bit_buffer, 0, 0, 0);

    return 0;

}
```

after debugging step by step: `*p_ch_bit=Cannot access memory at address 0x0` and  message error appear 'segmentation error.....'

please help me

Comment: In your `unpack` function, these variables are not used and you should remove them:  `ret_code`, `ch_bit`, and `ch_word`.  The variable `ch_bit` is assigned a value but never accessed.

Comment: Functions in C++ (and C), do not always need to return a value.  If you are always returning 0 from a function, change the function's return type to `void` and eliminate the `return` statement.

Comment: Try placing one parameter per line.  This makes your code easier to read (I have to keep scrolling horizontally to see all the parameters of `unpack`).

Comment: Also, consider removing some of the parameters to `unpack_code` since they are not being used by the function.

Comment: This is probably an *X-Y* question:  there are questions about the *bigger picture* that need to be answered rather than these lower level ones.  One indication is the call to `unpack_code` with all 0 values for parameters.

Comment: those parameters i'll use it after i'll pass this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void unpack_code(unsigned int **p_ch_beg, int *p_ch_bit, int *p_code, int numbits, int wsize,unsigned int erasemaks)

     unpack_code(                   NULL,          NULL,  bit_buffer,           0,         0,                     0);
```

If you line up your definition of and call to `unpack_code` you see that you are, in fact, passing `NULL` for the `p_ch_bit` argument. You need to fix that.

You probably need to do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct melp_param *par;

void unpack_code( unsigned int **p_ch_beg, int *p_ch_bit, 
        int *p_code, int numbits, int wsize,unsigned int erasemaks)
{
      int ret_code;
      int ch_bit;
      unsigned int *ch_word;
      ch_bit = *(p_ch_bit);
      *p_code = 0;

}

void melp_chn_read(struct melp_param *par, 
                   struct melp_param *prev_par)
{



}

int main(void)
{
    int bit_buffer[42];
    int code; // <------------------------------------------- this

    unpack_code(NULL, bit_buffer, &code, 0, 0, 0); // <------ and this

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You're passing in NULL for `p_ch_bit` and it is crashing when trying to dereference that pointer.

I'd suggest learning how to use a debugger to find out what's crashing on your own in the future. It will really help!

Comment: this  ch_bit = *(p_ch_bit); is crashing , if i comment it every thing is ok, i need solution suggestion please

Comment: Don't pass in NULL?  I'm not really sure what your program is trying to do.

Comment: And use better names... Hope I never have to maintain your code because there's no telling what it actually does.